# CSS text in forms that dissaprears when clicked?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have two problems with a form I am making, the first is the I want to throw some css onto a form. This works with my `<textarea>` box, as it has a closing tag and you can put the text in between. The `<input>` tags on the other hand have to get text trough the `value=""` tag, which doesn't respond to any of my CSS tries.

Secondly, I was wondering if it is possible to make the box clear itsself once it is clicked. (not sure if HTML forms support that)

Here is a link to the form with the css, so you can see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/D39rr/5/

Comment: While hiding the label when the user starts working with a form control is fashionable, please don't do it. It causes accessibility and usability problems (to varying degrees, depending on how it is implemented). The least problematic approach is to use a `<label>` and a transparent form control, then use absolute positioning and z-index to put them in the same spot. Putting the `<label>` *before* the form control inside of (graphically speaking) inside it is a better bet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input placeholder="Your email address" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LVuuY/).

To style the `placeholder` text (in compliant browsers):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
::-moz-input-placeholder,
::-o-input-placeholder,
::-ms-input-placeholder,
::input-placeholder {
    color: #0f0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LVuuY/3/).

To style the text, whether it's from the `value` attribute or user-entered, simply use the usual `color`, `font-style`, `font-weight`, etc:

```
input {
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LVuuY/1/).

Incidentally, the `textarea`, as you correctly note, 'has a closing tag.' Therefore it's *not* a self-closing (or void) element, and should *not* have a `/` character in its opening tag (as you do in your linked JS Fiddle: `<textarea id="style" name="message" />Type out your question here</textarea>`), instead it should be, simply:

```
<textarea id="style" name="message">Type out your question here</textarea>
```

Or, with the `placeholder`:

```
<textarea id="style" name="message" placeholder="Type out your question here"></textarea>
```

It's worth noting, also, that using the `placeholder` to replace a `label` means that any guidance offered is explicitly hidden once the user has focused, or entered data into, the field. If you don't want the `label` elements visible all the time, then one way to show the guidance only while the `input` is focused is:

```
label {
    display: inline;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

input:focus + label,
input:active + label {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}​
```

Which triggers the reveal once the `input` is focused/active: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LVuuY/5/).

Comment: No, placeholder isn't the solution here — the specification explicitly forbids using it as a replacement for a `<label>`.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the placeholder tag? It works fine and I don't think that it is needed for it to show extra info as it is a small and simple form. 

Is it actually wrong to use it, or does `<label>` just have more functionality?

Comment: The `label` is an accessibility aid, and explicit guidance/reminder/prompt for what the specific `input` (or `textarea`) element is for; it's there to help the user fill out the `form` that *you want them to fill out*. Removing it and replacing it with a transient element causes accessibility issues (what if the user forgets the format, or the details, of the field they're filling out; if the `label` isn't there how are they meant to remember?)

Comment: Or if they are using software that doesn't expose the placeholder (such as an older browser, or a screen reader that doesn't support it).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `placeholder` attribute. See David Walsh's article on [HTML5 Placeholder Styling with CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css) for both an example and styling information. The `placeholder` attribute has [fairly good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), except in IE. You can able to use Javascript to re-create the effect of the `placeholder` attribute though… I like to use the [Webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html) to progressively polyfill HTML5 form functionality (including other attributes like `type="date"` and `required="required"`).

Comment: No, placeholder isn't the solution here — the specification explicitly forbids using it as a replacement for a `<label>`.

Comment: Hmm… didn't think about that… So you would recommend something like the Javascript driven [in-field labels](http://streetpc.instanceof.me/jquery-infieldlabels/) plugin?

Comment: That's the least bad way to implement that kind of design that I've come across. I'd still go with the "Scroll bars exist, you don't need to be stingy with space" approach of having labels outside the controls.